# Finding how many elements from a list you need to reach a certain percentage coverage

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a long list x = [4,6,7,8,8,8,9,0,9,1,7,7]
I know I can use counter to see how many times an item appears.

```
x = [4,6,7,8,8,8,9,0,9,1,7,7]
from collections import Counter
Counter(x)

>>Counter({0: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 2})
```

I can sort them using:

```
Counter(x).most_common()

>>Counter(x).most_common()
Out[33]: [(7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (4, 1), (6, 1)]
```

Now, I want to know how many elements I need to cover 50% of my list. For example, 7 and 8 appear 6 times, there are 12 elements, so I only need 7 and 8 to cover 50% of the elements in the list. If I add 9, I have 8 elements, so 7, 8 and 9 cover 66% of the elements in the list.

If my list has hundreds of thousand of elements, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to cover `50%` of the list with the *fewest* different elements?

Comment: @JoeIddon Yes, that is what I want, or any percentage

Answer (score 3):

I'd just iterate over `most_common` and accumulate the items until reaching the given percentage of the list's `len`:

```
def common_elements(lst, pct):
    required = len(lst) * pct
    found = 0
    result = []
    for tup in Counter(lst).most_common():
        result.append(tup[0])
        found += tup[1]
        if found >= required:
            break
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

> If my list has hundreds of thousand of elements

You can write a generator function that *yields* items until the percentage of count is surpassed. Generator functions only respond to iteration, they never collect the results in memory, so the memory footprint of the function is minimal irrespective of the data size:

```
def func(lst, percentage=0.5):
    cnt = 0
    for x, y in Counter(lst).most_common():
        cnt += y
        if cnt > len(lst)*percentage:
            return
        yield x

for p in func(x):
    print(p)
# 7
# 8
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `numpy`, no loops are needed, and use concepts like binning, sorting, and counting to compute your result:

```
thresh = 0.5

vals, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
idx = counts.argsort()
vals = vals[idx][::-1]
w = np.where(np.cumsum(counts[idx][::-1]/len(x)) > thresh)[0][0]
print(vals[range(w)])

# for x = [4,6,7,8,8,8,9,0,9,1,7,7]
# the result is: [8, 7]
```

performance compare with @Moses

```
# large array
x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000)

# @Moses : 
timeit.timeit("moses()", setup="from __main__ import func, moses", number=1000)
Out[8]: 1.9789454049896449

# @this :
timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f1", number=1000)
Out[6]: 0.5699292980134487
```